# SQL INNER JOIN only returns the first result

Tags: mysql

I have a Many to Many relationship between Pets and Users, with a UserPets join table. I've been trying to write an SQL query that would return the user name with the amount of times walked. However, I've only been able to return a user and a timesWalked and they are not even the associated ones.

The current SQL statement I have is:

```
SELECT user_pets.timesWalked, users.name
FROM user_pets
    INNER JOIN users ON user_pets.user_id = users.id
```

And the returned result is:

```
[{"timesWalked"=>20, "name"=>"user1", 0=>20, 1=>"user1"}]
```

In this instance, user1 is not the one that walked the dog 20 times, which is the association I need.

```
table name: users
name 
user1
user2
user3

table name: user_pets
name    timesWalked    userId   petId
usep1    10               2       1
usep2    20               1       3
usep3     5               1       2

table name: pets
name
pet1
pet2
pet3
```

My expected result is:

```
[{"timesWalked"=>20, "name"=>"user1"}]
[{"timesWalked"=>10, "name"=>"user3"}]
[{"timesWalked"=>5, "name"=>"user2"}]
```

In this instance, the user name from the User's table is being associated with timesWalked from the user_pets table

How can I return all the timesWalked with all the user names who walked the pet?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text please, not images.

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: LEFT JOIN won't properly associate the name, it just returns all the timesWalked in descending order

Comment: Your current query is correct. It shows one result row per user_pets entry, namely the user and the times walked, omitting the information with which pet the user walked. If you think it returns only one row you are mistaken or your table data is different from what you think it is. I suppose you are using the query in some app you've written and only fetch the first row by mistake.

Comment: What makes you say that the query doesn't show the associated user? You say user1=20 is wrong because user1 didn't walk the pet 20 times, but then you want the same row in your requested result. You forgot the IDs in users and pets table, but I think user1 is id 1, and in that case user 1 *is* the one who walked one of the pets 20 times.

Comment: And your expected result doesn't match the data shown. Your user_pets table shows two records for user id 1 and one for user id 2, so how can you get three different users in your result?

Comment: i thought because the columns matched here user_pets.user_id = users.id it would return all instances and associate them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inner join to achieve this.
Below query lists all the users who have walked all the pets for total number of time.
i.e. User 1 has walked two pets for 2 times each.

```
select
    up.timesWalked, u.name as UserName, p.name as PetName
from user_pets up 
inner join users u on up.user_id = u.id
inner join pets p on up.pet_id = p.id
```

Have a look at this fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c91a1/2

Comment: Edited to get only results and not sum. If it answered your question then please mark it as an answer. Thanks